# When I use value in input , I can't type a text in input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When i want use `value={tempLogin.login}` i can't type in my input .
What did i do wrong ? I don't see mistakes in event,object and state :(

```
var loginInfo = {
    login: "",
    password: ""
};
const [tempLogin, addTempLogin] = React.useState(loginInfo);
const [logged, setLogged] = React.useState(0);
  const newLogin = event => {
    loginInfo.login = event.target.value;
    addTempLogin(loginInfo);
    console.log(tempLogin.login);
  };
return ....
          <TextField
            placeholder="Wpisz swoją nazwę użytkownika"
            type="text"
            id="name"
            onChange={newLogin}
          />
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use `var`** in React.

`tempLogin` is always re-initialized for every re-render to

```
{
    login: "",
    password: ""
}
```

Thus, `tempLogin.login` is always `""`.

Instead, have your `useState()` as:

```
React.useState({
    login: "",
    password: ""
});
```

or pass `loginInfo` as prop.